# Архитектура PHP приложения на laravel (Repository, Интеграция с API)

Tags: laravel, архитектура, репозиторий

Коллеги, хотел спросить как поступить, при проектировании приложения:

Есть два источника данных: БД и сторонний API

Пошастав по интернету, нашел, что и БД, и API нужно получать из репозиториев.

В целом с БД все ясно - создаем трейт с базовыми фунцкиями ORM (find, create, delete и т.д.), подключаем к репозиторию и используем в репе модель.

А вот как поступить с API?

Писать http запросы прям в репозитории, или выводить в отдельные классы? (т.к. там может присутствовать логика)

И получается, что я передаю массив данных в репозиторий, с репозитория передаю в другой класс.
Я просто не уверен, нормально ли это

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Репозиторий инкапсулирует набор объектов, сохраняемых в хранилище данных, и операции выполняемые над ними.([источник](https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/More/Repository/README.html))

На мой взгляд использовать репозитории для операций над данными полученнными по api - нормальный подход.

---

> создаем трейт с базовыми фунцкиями ORM

Можно и через трейт. На ваше усмотрение.

---

> Писать http запросы прям в репозитории, или выводить в отдельные классы

Конечно выносить в отдельный класс. Репозиторий предоставляет методы для операций над данными, но он не должен знать каким образом устроен источник данных и как с ним взаимодействовать. Иначе это нарушает [принцип единой ответственности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).

Репозиторий должен знать класс, через который он может получить доступ к данным.

На мой взгляд, простой пример реализации должен выглядеть так:

Api клиент:

```
class ApiProviderClient
{
    private $httpClient;
    private $address;
    private $key;

    public function __construct(\GuzzleHttp\Client $httpClient, string $address, string $key)
    {
        $this->httpClient = $httpClient;
        $this->address    = $address;
        $this->key        = $key;
    }

    public function getProducts(): array
    {
        $response = $this->httpClient->request('GET', $this->address, [
            'headers' => [
                'key' => $this->key,
            ],
        ]);

        return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents())->products;
    }
}
```

Репозиторий:

```
class ProviderRepository
{
    private $apiClient;

    public function __construct(ApiProviderClient $apiClient)
    {
        $this->apiClient = $apiClient;
    }

    public function find(array $params): Collection
    {
        $products = $this->apiClient->getProducts();
        //other logic filters

        return new Collection($products);
    }
}
```

Таким образом, репозиторий занимается только своим делом - оперирует данными. Клиент для api знает все о взаимодействии с провайдером(адреса, ключи, форматы).
Более того, клиент может понадобиться в других местах.

Так же выделение клиента в отдельный класс хорошо тем, что его можно будет легко подменить при тестировании и тем самым протестировать репозиторий или другие классы, которые с ним взаимодействуют.

---

> И получается, что я передаю массив данных в репозиторий, с репозитория передаю в другой класс. Я просто не уверен, нормально ли это

Это нормально. Главное позаботьтесь о том, чтобы репозиторий всегда возвращал одну и ту же структуру. Чтобы в случае замены клиента, репозиторий работал как и раньше. Для преобразования данных полученых от клиента к нужном типу(коллекции, объектам) можно воспользоваться [Data Mapper](https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/Structural/DataMapper/README.html).

Comment: О, отлично, спасибо! А вот если, от api может возвращать различные статусы ответов (не http), обрабатывать постоянно в контроллерах не охота, да и грязный ответ в контроллер с репозитория не охота отдавать .. Поступил пока так: сделал сервис, который обрывает исполнение приложения (типа исключение) и отдает json с соответствующим статусом, однако этот метод вызывается в классе, который делает запрос к API, а в контроллер мы вернемся, только с хорошим ответом.. Это норм, или совсем замудрил как-то ?

Comment: Бизнес логику обработки ответов можно реализовать в сервисе. То есть получается так - контроллер вызывает метод сервиса, сервис имеет доступ к репозиториям, получает данные от него, обрабатывает бизнес логику и возвращает ответ в коннтроллер(или кидает исключение). В итоге - бизнес логика в сервисе, операции с данными в репозитории, контроллер тонкий. Этот же сервис потом можно будет использовать в других контроллерах или консольных командах.